# How do I get hql string from DetachedCriteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, detachedcriteria

I'd like to get hql request from DetachedCriteria. Is there any right way of doing it(I mean toString is not right)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible since criteria is not mapped to hql but to sql. 
Seeing the sql should be easy with show_sql = true.

See also SO question : [StackOverflow is-there-any-easy-way-to-convert-criteria-to-hql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543656/is-there-any-easy-way-to-convert-criteria-to-hql)